# How to slice a multidimensional array in python/numpy in a way to select specific row, column and depth?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert my MATLAB code to python but I'm having some issues. This code is supposed to segment letters from a picture.

Here's the whole code in MATLAB:

```
he = imread('r.jpg');
imshow(he);
%C = makecform(type) creates the color transformation structure C that defines the color space conversion specified by type.
cform = makecform('srgb2lab'); 
%To perform the transformation, pass the color transformation structure as an argument to the applycform function.
lab_he = applycform(he,cform);
%convert to double precision 
ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
%size of dimension in 2D array
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);

%B = reshape(A,sz1,...,szN) reshapes A into a sz1-by-...-by-szN array where
%sz1,...,szN indicates the size of each dimension. You can specify a single
% dimension size of [] to have the dimension size automatically calculated,
% such that the number of elements in B matches the number of elements in A.
% For example, if A is a 10-by-10 matrix, then reshape(A,2,2,[]) reshapes
% the 100 elements of A into a 2-by-2-by-25 array.
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
nColors = 3;

[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
                                      'Replicates',3);
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');
segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);

for k = 1:nColors
    color = he;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end

figure,imshow(segmented_images{1}), title('objects in cluster 1');
figure,imshow(segmented_images{2}), title('objects in cluster 2');
figure,imshow(segmented_images{3}), title('objects in cluster 3');

mean_cluster_value = mean(cluster_center,2);
[tmp, idx] = sort(mean_cluster_value);
blue_cluster_num = idx(1);

L = lab_he(:,:,1);
blue_idx = find(pixel_labels == blue_cluster_num);
L_blue = L(blue_idx);
is_light_blue = im2bw(L_blue,graythresh(L_blue));

% target_labels = repmat(uint8(0),[nrows ncols]);
% target_labels(blue_idx(is_light_blue==false)) = 1;
% target_labels = repmat(target_labels,[1 1 3]);
% blue_target = he;
% blue_target(target_labels ~= 1) = 0;
% figure,imshow(blue_target), title('blue');
```

Here's what I have in Python so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import sys



img = cv2.imread('r.jpg',1)
print "original image: ", img.shape

cv2.imshow('BGR', img)

img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
cv2.imshow('RGB', img1)
cv2.imshow('LAB', img2) #differs from the LAB color space in MATLAB (need to patch maybe?)

print "LAB converted image: ", img2.shape
print "LAB converted image dimension", img2.ndim #says the image is a 3 dimensional array

img2a = img2.shape[2][1:2]
print "Slicing the LAB converted image", img2a


#we need to convert that to double precision 
print img2.dtype


img2a = img2.astype(np.uint64) #convert to double precision 
print img2a.dtype

#print img2a
row =  img2a.shape[0] #returns number of rows of img2a
column = img2a.shape[1] #returns number of columns of img2a

print "row: ", row #matches the MATLAB version
print "column: ", column #matchees the MATLAB version
rowcol =  row * column

k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
    cv2.imwrite('final image',final_image)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now the part i'm currently stuck in is that here in Matlab code, I have lab_he(:,:,2:3) which means all the rows and all the columns from depth 2 and 3. However when I try to replicate that in Python img2a = img2.shape[2][1:2] but it doesn't work or makes sense. Please help.

Comment: Why did you do something completely different in Python? You didn't do `size(lab_he)(3)(2:3)` in Matlab; why would you do `img2.shape[2][1:2]` in Python?

Comment: @user2357112 `size(lab_he)(2)(2:3)` is not valid syntax in MATLAB.  You unfortunately have to assign temporary variables as a means for intermediate slicing.  That's how MATLAB has always worked and some of us don't like it :(.

Comment: I wonder if I got the problem correctly. Could you give an example? At the moment, it seems easy to me:

`a = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]] --> print a[1:3]`

yields: `[[[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]], [[19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27]]]`, which are the rows and columns from layers 2 and 3.

Comment: @rayryeng `img2.shape[2][1:2]` still seems...odd:) I believe OP just needs `img2[:,:,1:3]` or the same with permuted indices.

Comment: `size(x)(2)(2:3)` is valid syntax, but it returns an `out of bounds` error.  `size(x)(2)` is a single number, a 1x1 matrix, e.g. `size(size(x)(2))`.  The `numpy` expression tries to do the same thing, except `x.shape[2]` is a scalar, not a tuple, and can't be indexed.

Comment: @hpaulj it's valid in octave and not MATLAB. It's one of those nice features I wish MATLAB had.

Comment: @user2357112 When i do img.shape in python I get (455L, 621L, 3L), which is 455 rows, 621 columns and 3 depth. Now in matlab this line 
ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3)) 
would get all the rows, all the columns and depth 2 and 3, the converts it to double precision, but I don't know how to do that in Python.

Comment: @shideh: `whatever.shape` in NumPy is the equivalent of `size(whatever)` in Matlab. Why are you trying to go through `img.shape` at all?

Comment: @user2357112 correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't lab_he(:,:,2:3) in MATLAB mean (for what I have) 455 rows, 621 columns and 2nd and 3rd depths? That's why I'm using shape to see how many rows, columns and depths I have.

Comment: @shideh: Are you trying to extract part of your array, or are you trying to figure out how big it is? `lab_he(:, :, 2:3)` extracts part of your array, while `img.shape` tells you how big your array is. Trying to index or slice `img.shape` to get pieces of `img` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In Octave/MATLAB

```
octave:29> x=reshape(1:(2*3*4),3,2,4);
octave:30> x(:,:,2:3)
ans =    
ans(:,:,1) =
    7   10
    8   11
    9   12

ans(:,:,2) =

   13   16
   14   17
   15   18

octave:31> size(x(:,:,2:3))
ans =
   3   2   2

octave:33> x(:,:,2:3)(2,2,:)
ans(:,:,1) =  11
ans(:,:,2) =  17
```

In `numpy`:

```
In [13]: x=np.arange(1,1+2*3*4).reshape(3,2,4,order='F')
In [14]: x[:,:,1:3]
Out[14]: 
array([[[ 7, 13],
        [10, 16]],

       [[ 8, 14],
        [11, 17]],

       [[ 9, 15],
        [12, 18]]])
In [15]: _.shape
Out[15]: (3, 2, 2)

In [17]: x[:,:,1:3][1,1,:]
Out[17]: array([11, 17])
```

Or with numpy normal 'C' ordering, and indexing on the 1st dimension

```
In [18]: y=np.arange(1,1+2*3*4).reshape(4,2,3)
In [19]: y[1:3,:,:]
Out[19]: 
array([[[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]],

       [[13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]]])
In [20]: y[1:3,:,:][:,1,1]
Out[20]: array([11, 17])
```

Same indexing ideas, though matching numbers and shapes requires some care, not only with the 0 v 1 index base.  A 3d array is displayed in a different arangement.  Octave divides it into blocks on the last index (its primary iterator), numpy iterates on the first index.

In 3d it makes more sense to talk about first, 2nd, 3rd dimensions rather than row,col,depth.  In 4d you run out of names. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to reshape array at specific depth, and I programmed a little recursive function to do so:

```
def recursive_array_cutting(tab, depth, i, min, max):

    if(i==depth):
        tab = tab[min:max]
        return tab

    temp_list = []
    nb_subtab = len(tab)

    for index in range(nb_subtab):

        temp_list.append(recursive_array_cutting(tab[index], depth, i+1, min, max))

    return np.asanyarray(temp_list)
```

It allow to get all array/values between the min and the max of a specific depth, for instance, if you have a (3, 4) tab = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]] and only want the last two values of the deepest array, you call like this : tab = recursive_array_cutting(tab, 1, 0, 0, 2) to get the output : [[0 1][0 1][0 1]].

If you have a more complexe array like this tab = [[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 3]], [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 3]], [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 3]]] (3, 3, 4) and want a (3, 2, 4) array, you can call like this :  tab = recursive_array_cutting(tab, 1, 0, 0, 2) to get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Xpu.png), and get rid of the last dimension in depth 1.

Function like this surely exist in numpy, but I did not found it.